# CL3 400MHZ Vs. CL4 800MHZ RAM

Tags: memory

I'm looking to purchase new RAM for a desktop computer I own, it takes DDR2 only. I've been reading more about the speed and latency and I'm still a little confused. Which would be the better buy between CL3 400Mhz RAM and CL4 800MHz RAM? Thanks!

Comment: Generally, it's better to get the higher speed unless other components could slow your PC down. I suggest you post your the rest of your configuration.

Comment: Okay thanks, here's a run down on the rest of my system: http://imgur.com/a/mcTdC

Comment: According to the [faq], shopping/buying recommendations are off topic on Super User. You can try your look in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access).

Comment: Before choosing, you should make sure that your system actually supports both DDR2-400 and DDR2-800. Most systems only support a couple of different clock speeds, and the RAM modules themselves can usually only downclock by one step. For instance, if your system supports DDR2-800 and 667, then DDR2-400 isn't even an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CL4 DDR2-800 has a theoretical latency of 10ns (2.5ns x 4), whereas
CL3 DDR2-400 has a theoretical latency of 15ns (5ns x 3).

CL4 DDR2-800 RAM wins in context of latency and since it has a higher frequency it wins also bandwidth wise. So CL4 DDR2-800 is your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say go for the CL4 800MHz. It should give you better performance.

Answer (score 1):

800 MHz RAM would be more beneficial. I don't believe that you will notice a difference between CL3 and CL4. More on the topic here > http://bit.ly/WvL1eY